# Java CDI not kicking in

Tags: java, maven, weld

So, my first attempt at CDI kind of went to the dogs. I've read a ton of articles and tried a variety of simple to complex examples without success. Here is my current, simple example. What am I doing wrong?

Maven Project:

**beans.xml** (located in src/main/resources/META-INF)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.1" 
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

**Printer.java**

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Printer {
    @Inject Greeting greeting;
}
```

**Greeting.java**

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.Default;

@Default
public class Greeting {
    public void sayStuff(){ System.out.println("Stuff"); }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new Printer().greeting.sayStuff();
    }
}
```

**The Error**
It builds fine, but on attempted run I get the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.foo.app.CDI_test.Main.main(Main.java:5)

which is precisely when I attempt to invoke `sayStuff()` on the greeting-property.
Why is it not being instantiated? Tutorials claim @Default to be excessive as well. I've attempted using both a custructor-injection and setter-injection, no cigar.

**EDIT 1** - added pom.xml dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId> 
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId> 
        <version>1.1</version> 
        <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency> 
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId> 
        <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId> 
        <version>2.2.4.Final</version> 
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

**EDIT 2** - version information
- Java 1.7
- Eclipse Luna 4.4.0
- IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDI runs fine in Java EE container

e.g. try a webapp, jsp/jsf page inside weblogic

In Java SE, you may need to do more

[What is the easiest way to have CDI and JPA in Java SE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935977/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-have-cdi-and-jpa-in-java-se)

http://blog.rocketscience.io/dependency-injection-with-cdi-in-java-se/

when you do `new Printer()` who is responsible for injecting stuff in your object?

Comment: Weld CDI should not be dependant on it being a webapp, should it?

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, I've read at least 5 different articles where beans are fetched without having to explicitly ask through a container!

Comment: I can give them a try, link please?

Comment: Found 2 in the log least:
https://code.google.com/p/jee6-cdi/wiki/DependencyInjectionAnIntroductoryTutorial_Part1
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/cdi-basic007.htm

Comment: AutomatedTellerMachine atm = beanContainer.getBeanByType(AutomatedTellerMachine.class) ??

Comment: As Kalpesh is trying to tell you: CDI is not "magic", someone will have to initialize the Application. In a Java SE environment, that someone is you.

Comment: I spent between 7 and 8 hours reading tutorials and yet that was the impression I was left with. My apologies and thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 1):

There is no dependency between CDI/Weld and EE.  It works fine in SE.  In order to run it in SE though you need to start the container.  This is typically done by:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Weld weld = new Weld();
    WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
    Printer printer = CDI.current().select(Printer.class).get();
    printer.getGreeting().sayStuff();
}
```

What you cannot do is direct field access, so `printer.greeting` won't work, hence you need to add a getter.  In addition, I use `CDI.current()` to access the runtime.  You'll also need to add `org.jboss.weld.se:weld-se` to your maven dependencies.  Take a look at [the weld docs](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#_java_se) for reference.